# Getting empty JSON from mongolab after GET request in node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, mongodb

My problem: I'm trying to `HTTP.GET` a *random* `questionSchema` from my database but it returns `""`. 
 In my database (that is hosted in [mongolab](https://mongolab.com/) I have a few different collections, but in my questions collection I only have 3 different JSONs with 3 different [questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJtfg.png).

I have a `Schema` that looks like this:

```
var questionSchema = new Schema({
    description: String    
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema);
```

In my `routes.js` I put the following:

```
app.get('/api/getrandomquestion', function (req, res) {
        if (req.params.description) {
            res.json(req.description);
        } else {
            res.json("");
        }

    });
```

I also have a service called `QuestionService.js` which is supposed to query the DB and give me back a *random* JSON document out of all (3) the documents that exist there. This is the code of the service:

```
var numberOfItemsToFind = 3;

Question.find({}, { '_id': 1}, function(err, data){
    if (err) res.send(err);
    var arr = shuffle.(data.slice(0));
    arr.splice(numberOfItemsToFind, arr.length - numberOfItemsToFind);
    var return_arr = [];
    async.each(arr, function(item, callback){
        Question.findById(item._id, function(err, data){
            if (err) res.send(err);
            return_arr.push(data);

            callback();
        });
    }, function(err){
        res.json(return_arr);
    });
});
```

And lastly, I put these together with my `questionCtrl`:

```
controller('QuestionCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $modal) {

    $http.get('/api/getrandomquestion').success(function (question) {

        $scope.description  = question.description;
    });
});
```

I am using [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) to make a `HTTP.GET` request to [localhost:3000/getrandomquestion](http://localhost:3000/getrandomquestion) and I'm getting back just the `""` as I stated.

Any help towards solving my problem (empty JSON instead of a real one) will be  **greatly appreciated**!

Comment: Do you have the body parser module?

Comment: Have you checked your server logs to make sure you're getting the request and everything is going smoothly?

Comment: @JamesonYu I have this : var bodyParser      = require('body-parser'); in my server.js file. (I run my app with "node server" ), if that's what you meant.

Comment: Your `HTTP.GET` request should be `localhost:3000/api/getrandomquestion`

Comment: @Idos I meant more like this: 

`app.use(bodyParser.json());`
`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`

Comment: @ShaohaoLin my GET path is correct as it works with other GET methods I have in place (otherwise I would get a 404).

Comment: @JamesonYu I don't have that. What would be the benefit of adding those?

Comment: @Idos This makes the body parser functionality available in your request, so express knows how to handle key, value pairs.

Comment: @JamesonYu I have been successful in fetching (via GET) other documents (other collections) from my db in the same way (just not with my random function...) , so i guess express works as expected and no additional "requires" are needed... ?

Comment: I mean when you are using POSTMAN. Your request in POSTMAN is `localhost:3000/getrandomquestion`, but you get request in angular controller is `localhost:3000/api/getrandomquestion`. Just double check, it helps to narrow down the problem from front-end side or back-end side.

Comment: @ShaohaoLin you are right, and I am evidently running the correct request ( http://localhost:3000/api/getrandomquestion ) in POSTMAN. Also otherwise I would get a 404 error instead of an empty string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `routes.js`:

```
app.get('/api/getrandomquestion', function (req, res) {
    if (req.params.description) {
        res.json(req.description);
    } else {
        res.json("");
    }
});
```

`req.params.description` is undefined. So the if statement failed.

If param `description` is not necessary, You should probably define your `GET` API like this:

```
app.get('/api/getrandomquestion', function (req, res) {
   QuestionService.getRandomQuestion(function(questions){
     res.json(questions);
   //res.send(questions);
   });
});
```

Basically your backend receive a GET `getrandomquestions` API call, you just forward to fetch MongoDB using `QuestionService`.

Comment: I will test this out shortly. Lets assume it works, what if I want to not pass the description but just get a random question? Do I have to have the param :description in my app.get  ?

Comment: In your case, you don't need to pass `description` as param. When you have the `GET` request from front-end, just forward to your `QuestionService` to fetch the random data function with a callback function.

Comment: I am getting a TypeError: QuestionService.getRandomQuestion is not a function .  Since there is really no function called getRandomQuestion.. How can i refer to the function that we meant to refer?

Comment: This is just an arbitrary function I named it. What is the name of the function that you use to get random question from MongoDB?

Comment: That's exactly the Question.find...  I have in QuestionService.js which is attached to the question

Comment: Do you include `QuestionService.js` in app.js?

Comment: Yes I do: var QuestionService = require('../public/js/services/QuestionService');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97309/discussion-between-idos-and-shaohao-lin).